NextJs 14 Dynamic Sitemap Issue on Live Envioment
I am having an issue with the dynamic sitemap.
I have this sitemap.ts file in the app route folder.
import type { MetadataRoute } from "next";

async function fetchSitemapData() {
  const response = await fetch("https://web.fvsols.com/api/sitemaphtml/all");
  console.log("response of sitemap: ", response);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log("response of sitemap data:  ", data);
  return data;
}

export default async function sitemap(): Promise<MetadataRoute.Sitemap> {
  const baseUrl = "https://fwebsouls.soulservices.com";
  const response = await fetchSitemapData();

  const pageResponse = response?.pages?.map((page: any) => {
    return {
      url: `${baseUrl}/${page?.slug}`,
      lastModified: page?.updated_at,
      changeFrequency: "always",
      priority: 0.9,
    };
  }) || [];

  const blogCategoriesResponse = response?.blogcategories?.map((blogCategory: any) => {
    return {
      url: `${baseUrl}/blog/${blogCategory?.slug}`,
      lastModified: blogCategory?.updated_at,
      changeFrequency: "always",
      priority: 0.9,
    };
  }) || [];

  const blogResponse = response?.blogs?.map((blog: any) => {
    return {
      url: `${baseUrl}/blog/${blog?.slug}`,
      lastModified: blog?.updated_at,
      changeFrequency: "always",
      priority: 0.9,
    };
  }) || [];

  const faqCategoriesResponse = response?.faqcategories?.map((faqCategory: any) => {
    return {
      url: `${baseUrl}/blog/${faqCategory?.slug}`,
      lastModified: faqCategory?.updated_at,
      changeFrequency: "always",
      priority: 0.9,
    };
  }) || [];

  return [
    {
      url: baseUrl,
      lastModified: new Date(),
      changeFrequency: "always",
      priority: 1.0,
    },
    ...pageResponse,
    ...blogCategoriesResponse,
    ...blogResponse,
    ...faqCategoriesResponse
  ];
}

This is the code that I am using. In development, if we create the build and run it, it will show the URL sets. However, on the live environment, the same build is not showing the URL sets. I don't know why
